# Using custom global modules in python virtual environment

Tags: python

I have 4 different python projects (4 different virtual environments) and I have one module / script that I wanted share between them somehow.

So my 'shared' module exposes a function called `send_log` and I want to be able to call this function from all those 4 different projects and I'm really trying to avoid code duplication, as it's quite a big module (loads other modules internally).

I don't really know where to even start. I tried googling `global modules python environment` but I usually get scenarios, where there are modules installed through `pip` on a system `python` and they try to import those. But my scenario is that my module is custom, something I've built basically..

Comment: You can create a package including your tools and install it locally like `cd my_tools && python setup.py install --user`. If you're using Linux or OS X, your package will be installed in your `$HOME/.local` and will be available for your local projects in virtal envs.

Comment: Thank you, this led me to the right direction. The only thing was, I had to run this from within `pipenv shell`.